# How to read real-time frequencies from a microphone input?

Tags: c#, .net, signal-processing, audio-processing, frequency-analysis

I want to get frequencies of a voice input acquired from microphone in real-time. I searched about this and got to know about FFT and another 2, 3 algorithms but implementing those algorithms seemed very complicated.

I am looking for a C# library that enable me to simply get frequencies into an array without having to implement it.

Comment: Apart from FFT what algorithms you think you need to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, like you guessed, signal processing are the kind of algorithms you do not want to implement yourself because there are quite complex.

Apparently, for C#, you can find some libraries out there but here is a good library performing DFT/FFT, and currently active : [DSPLib](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1107480/dsplib-fft-dft-fourier-transform-library-for-net)

> DSPLib has several main parts, but it's basic goal is to allow a real
>   Fourier Transform to be preformed on a time series input array,
>   resulting in a usable classic spectrum output without any further
>   tweaking required by the user.

If I understood correctly what you wanted, the 2nd example is the task you want to achieve (it lacks the recording from the mic).

**Just one piece of advice, be careful with the windowing as it can influence the spectrum of your signal.**

**Just one note on a concept which could let you puzzled, the zero padding is just a trick to have a number of samples equals to a power of 2, in order to use the FFT algorithm. Therefore, the resulted spectrum is somehow 'artificially' produced with a better resolution.**

```
void example2()
{
  // Same Input Signal as Example 1 - Except a fractional cycle for frequency.
  double amplitude = 1.0; double frequency = 20000.5;
  UInt32 length = 1000; UInt32 zeroPadding = 9000; // NOTE: Zero Padding
  double samplingRate = 100000;

  double[] inputSignal = DSPLib.DSP.Generate.ToneSampling(amplitude, frequency, samplingRate, length);

  // Apply window to the Input Data & calculate Scale Factor
  double[] wCoefs = DSP.Window.Coefficients(DSP.Window.Type.Hamming, length);
  double[] wInputData = DSP.Math.Multiply(inputSignal, wCoefs);
  double wScaleFactor = DSP.Window.ScaleFactor.Signal(wCoefs);

  // Instantiate & Initialize a new DFT
  DSPLib.DFT dft = new DSPLib.DFT();
  dft.Initialize(length, zeroPadding); // NOTE: Zero Padding

  // Call the DFT and get the scaled spectrum back
  Complex[] cSpectrum = dft.Execute(wInputData);

  // Convert the complex spectrum to note: Magnitude Format
  double[] lmSpectrum = DSPLib.DSP.ConvertComplex.ToMagnitude(cSpectrum);

  // Properly scale the spectrum for the added window
  lmSpectrum = DSP.Math.Multiply(lmSpectrum, wScaleFactor);

  // For plotting on an XY Scatter plot generate the X Axis frequency Span
  double[] freqSpan = dft.FrequencySpan(samplingRate);

  // At this point a XY Scatter plot can be generated from,
  // X axis => freqSpan
  // Y axis => lmSpectrum
}
```

After plotting, here is the result :

[image: signal spectrum]

With a zoom-in on the peak of the spectrum :

[image: signal spectrum zoom]